# String as an Object

Tags: java, string, object

From what I understand, in Java, if you give object2 the value of object1, and then if you change either object1 or object 2, the other will change as well. However, with Strings (which I've learned are objects?), changing one string won't change a different string. Here's an example below. Changing s1 doesn't change s2, even though s2 was assigned the value of s1. Can anyone explain?

```
String s1 = "Ant";
String s2 = s1;
s1 = "Man";
```

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: If the language is Java, then s1 and s2 are *NOT* "objects".  They are object references.  `s1 = "Man;` completely changes the object s1 refers to.  The original object, "Ant", automatically becomes available for garbage collection.

Comment: Java, Foggy what do you mean by object references?

Comment: *"and change one of the objects"* ... where do you do that in your second example? You're just reassigning the variable `s1` and nothing more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the language is Java...

... then s1 and s2 are NOT "objects". They are [object references](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=174371&seqNum=4).

`s1 = "Man";` completely changes the object that s1 refers to. The original object value, "Ant", is no longer accessible to your program and automatically becomes available for garbage collection.

This article explains further:

http://way2java.com/oops-concepts/reference-variables-anonymous-objects/

Comment: Is every possible string in java already a preset object then, and if you say s1 = "Man" then it just points s1 towards that already existing object memory location?

Comment: In Java, strings are "immutable": When you declare `String s1 = "Ant";`, "Ant" is created on the heap.  It can be shared, but the value itself cannot be altered.  Look here: [Why is String immutable](http://java.dzone.com/articles/why-string-immutable-java).  And yes, ["String literals"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/literals.html) (like "Ant" and "Man" in your examples) are created at compile time and carried around in your binary .class file.  But a "String" in general can be created on-the-fly (just like any other variable type).

Comment: IMPORTANT TAKEWAY: "s1" isn't the "object" itself.  It merely *refers* to "the object".